# Getting the nearest value that returns true on a bool

Tags: c#, math, numbers, integer, boolean

If I wanted to get the nearest value to a number, but that value also has to return true on a bool called `IsMultipleOf7` which returns true on numbers that are multiples of 7.

For example, I have a `int x = 523`. So the nearest multiple of 7 is 525, so my bool would return true 525.

How can I get that number?

Comment: The most obvious thing I can think of is testing the number x, then test the numbers below and above, then the numbers two below and two above, etc. etc. and continue in this fashion: A brute force.

Comment: I'd prefer if there was another way to do it rather than brute forcing, as my real number that I have is huge, and brute forcing would definitely slow down the speed of the program I'm making. It'd be awesome if there was something like .Where in IEnumerable, where it can just skip all the ones that return false in the bool.

Comment: When would it return false? The requirements are unclear.

Comment: If your Boolean condition is arbitrary (as in could be literally anything), then brute force is the only solution in general.  If you're really just looking to round to the nearest multiple of some integer, that's considerably simpler.

Comment: One line of code, no BOOL needed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33324281/2057171

Answer (score 1):

This function will return the closest multiple of `7` or the number itself if it is a multiple of `7`

```
public int GetClosestNumber(int number, out bool isMultipleOf7)
    {
    // if the number is a multiple of 7 isMultipleOf7 is set to true
    isMultipleOf7 = number%7 == 0;

    if (isMultipleOf7)
    {
        // if it's a multiple of 7 then the closest one is the number itself
        return number;
    }

    // if it's not a multiple of 7 then try find the closest.
    var lower = number - (number % 7);
    var upper = (number + 7) - (number %7);
    var diffL = Math.Abs(number - lower);
    var diffU = Math.Abs(number - upper);

    return diffL > diffU ? upper : lower;
}
```

And here's a usage example:

```
bool IsMultipleOf7;
// Following line will output: Closest multiple of 7 is: 525
Console.WriteLine("Closest multiple of 7 is: {0}", 
                   GetClosestNumber(523, out IsMultipleOf7)); 
// Following line will output: The number itself is not a multiple of 7"
Console.WriteLine("The number itself is {0} a multiple of 7", 
                   IsMultipleOf7 ? string.Empty: "not");
```

[Live demo is also available here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/coBGmd)

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 523;
while ((int)x/7!=(decimal)x/7){
    x++;
}
return x;
```

Comment: What if x = 526? Closest is still 525, but your code will return 532.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of. The first is the brute force method I commented about. If you start with the number `x`, test it. If it works, hooray! If not, try adding one to x and test. Then subtract one from x and test. Then do this with two, and three, testing up and down at the same time. Once your test returns true, you have located (one of) the closest number(s) that work. This method is a general one and will work with any test function.

Because we know you are using `IsMultipleOf7` as the test, a smarter method could be possible. Imagine the time it would take if your test was instead `IsMultipleOf999999999`! So many numbers might have to tested before hitting the closest. Instead, some math can be used. First, compute x modulo 7 (for `IsMultipleOf7`), written `x % 7` in C(++). This value tells you how far x is from the largest multiple of 7 LESS than x. If this value is 0, x is a multiple of 7. If the value is 1, 2 or 3, x *minus* the value is the closest multiple. If the value is 4, 5 or 6, x *plus* the difference to make 7 (`7 - value`) is the closest multiple.

Some pseudo-code:

```
x = 523
value = x modulo 7
if(value == 0):
  return x
if(value < 4): // that is, less than half of 7
  return x - value
otherwise
  return x + (7 - value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 523;

int result = ((x / 7) + 1) * 7;
```

You may need a more complex formula, if your number is dividable by 7 and should stay the same number. Or maybe you have simplified your problem too much?

Answer (score 0):

`x=7*Math.Round(((float)x)/7.0)`

^Simplest solution right there ;)

No need for all of this looping and stuff.

divide by 7, if the decimals are less than 0.5 then the nearest denominator is floored, else ceiling. Round() does that for you, then just multiply your new int by 7 to create a number evenly divisible by 7 (since it was an int being multiplied by 7). It will get the closest value above *or* below. No need for bool at all. Make sure you cast float onto x so that it can be divided by 7 without causing flooring with integer logic.